# Shift z exponents in transfer function

Tags: filtering

I have calculated a transfer function for an IIR filter: (-0.0729597 + 0.0729597 z^2)/(0.854081 + 0.71172 z + 1. z^2)

But it doesn't have the right exponents for z, as I would like them to start at z^0 and go down (z^-1, z^-2) etc.

Is there a simple way to do this?

//Couldnt get formatting to work...
[image]

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: Cut and paste the actual code (not an image) and formatting should work just fine.